# Do interfaces have toString method?

Tags: java, interface

How is it possible to call `toString` method using the reference variable of interface `Test`, which does not have a `toString` method?

```
interface Test
{
    void show();
    String toHi();
}
class Demo implements Test
{
    public void show(){
        System.out.println("Show");
    }
    public String toString(){
        return "Hello"; 
    }
    public String toHi(){
        return "Hi";    
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Test t=new Demo();
        String s=t.toString();
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: What happened when you tried it? Alternatively, how would you construct an implementation of the interface that didn't extend Object?

Comment: actully i want to know that how toString() method called by an interface reference variable m.

Comment: Because, as I hinted, you *can't* construct an implementation of the interface that *doesn't* extend Object. So any implementation declares or inherits a toString() method, so you can call it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The the **Java Documentation says...**

`When an interface has no direct SuperInterface, it will create abstract public method for  all those public methods present in the Object class`.

This is why you are able to call the `toString()` method on the interface reference

Comment: if it default created a abstract public methods.. why are we not forced to implement the method in the concrete class which implements it???.. it does not give out any compilation exception.!!! in Short Interface A has override toString() from object. Class B implements IA. shouldn't class implement toString() ??

Comment: @PunithRaj If class B not extends any class then it is implicitly extends Object class. Object class having the implementation for that abstract methods.

Answer (score 11):

`Object` has a [`toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString()) method, so *everything* (except primitive types) has a `toString()` method. Java will treat anything, even an empty interface, as having all the methods of `Object`, because it always does.

Comment: But,it is not written in java documentation that an interface extends an Object class.
Class Object is the root of the class hierarchy. Every class has Object as a superclass. All objects, including arrays, implement the methods of this class.

and let say, if an interface extends Object class so what about non abstract method which is defined in Object class..
and as i know that an interface can only extends interfaces, but here Object is not an interface.... ???

Comment: The op means how the toString() method was called on Interface reference... Interface never extends Object class....

Comment: @AkhileshDharDubey Interfaces don't extend classes—that's not possible. Java has a specific special case where an interface that doesn't extend any other interface implicitly includes all the methods on `Object`. And it *is* documented.

Comment: @John Calsbeek you are right at this...but the situation in which it does is in my answer...

Comment: @KumarVivekMitra But if we do not declare String toHi(); method in My interface, It will give compiletion error. i.e.
C.java:25: error: cannot find symbol
                String s1=m.toHi();
                           ^
  symbol:   method toHi()
  location: variable m of type My
1 error

Comment: @AkhileshDharDubey first of all if you dont declare the toHi() method in Inteface it give `HELLO` as output, and if you remove toHi() from Interface and toString() method from class C, it gives the default reply of `getClass().getName()@hashCode` ie `(com.chat.C@360be0)`. I had to delete my answer because some ignorant user gave it a negative mark, before trying it out..and i am really sorry that i gave the correct answers to such ignorant people...

Comment: @KumarVivekMitra A wrong downvote isn't much of a reason for deleting a correct answer.

Comment: @EJP as you said it...i am undeleting my answer...

Comment: @JohnCalsbeek how interfaces includes all the methods of Object class ?

Answer (score 6):

Any `Object` has a `toString()` method. Anything that would implement an interface will implicitly extend `Object`, so will also have a `toString()` method.

Answer (score 2):

Class `C` implements `My` but it also extends `Object`, as all objects eventually do in their inheritance tree.

The [`Object`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html) class does have the method `toString()`, along with a number of others.

Answer (score 2):

Since class `Demo` implicitly `extends` class `Object`, it inherits method `toString`. And since that's not an `abstract` method, class `Demo` is not forced to provide an implementation, although you're able to directly invoke `toString` on an instance of `Demo`. For more information, please see [Lesson: Interfaces and Inheritance](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/).

As stated in the [`Object`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html) API,

> Class `Object` is the root of the class hierarchy. Every class has
>   `Object` as a superclass. All objects, including arrays, implement the
>   methods of this class.

Also, note that the `toString` method is not part of the interface definition, but rather the `Object` class definition.

Answer (score 2):

The reason that you are able to invoke that method through that variable of your interfce is because of a special treatment in case of interfaces in Java.

Even though the method is not explicitly declared in the interface, the special treatment implicitly provides declarations for all the public instance methods defined in the class `Object`. And the `toString` method is one of them.

But, note that interfaces don't implicitly extend any super interface (or class) unlike classes which implicitly extend the `Object` class.

You will find a better explanation here - [Do Interfaces really inherit the Object class in Java?](http://geekexplains.blogspot.com/2008/06/do-interfaces-really-inherit-from-class.html)
.

Answer (score 1):

[toString](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString()) is declared inside `Object`. When an `Object` implements an interface it must have a `toString` method.

Therefore any object reference, be it an interface or an enum must have all the object methods:

- clone
- equals
- finalize
- getClass
- hashCode
- notify
- notifyAll
- **toString**
- wait

Answer (score 0):

Every Object(except primitive types)  in java has a toString() method.

Comment: primitive types are not objects (and you forgot to mention that interfaces are not objects either)